# Google cloud download file cors issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to download a file from my google cloud bucket but when I do I get the following cors issue

```
ADPU128524NIC#:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 
'https://storage.googleapis.com/<MY-BUCKET-NAME>/myimage.png' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' 
has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check:
 No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

How can I fix this cors issue?

I have tried setting up cors with gcloud cli using the following command

`gcloud storage buckets update gs://<MY-BUCKET-NAME> --cors-file=cors.json`

The contents of my cors.json file are

```
[
    {
      "origin": ["*"],
      "method": ["*"],
      "responseHeader": ["Content-Type"],
      "maxAgeSeconds": 3600
    }
]
```

and when I run to double check this command

`gcloud storage buckets describe gs://<MY-BUCKET-NAME> --format="default(cors)"`

I get the following response

```
cors:
- maxAgeSeconds: 3600
  method:
  - '*'
  origin:
  - '*'
  responseHeader:
  - Content-Type
```

but I still cannot download a file from my google cloud storage.

most tutorials on the internet tell me to go into my bucket settings and view the permission tab and then view the Cors tab. The Cors tab does not exist in my cloud console

[no cors tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFYDt.png)

my download function looks like this

```
  const download = () => {
    // props.url = https://storage.googleapis.com/${bucket.name}/${blob.name}
    const url = `${props.url}`;

    const headers = {
      Authorization: "Bearer " + process.env.REACT_APP_STORAGE_TOKEN,
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "http://localhost:3000",
    };
    axios({
      method: "GET",
      headers,
      url,
      responseType: "blob",
    })
      .then((response) => {
        setIsDownloading(false);
        const href = URL.createObjectURL(response.data);
        var link = document.createElement("a");
        link.href = href;
        link.setAttribute(
          "download",
          replace("%", " ", props.name.split("?")[0])
        );
        link.click();
        URL.revokeObjectURL(href);
      })
      .then((data) => {});
  };
```

Comment: Maybe your browser has cached the previous CORS response? Try clearing cache.. ?

Comment: let me try doing that

Comment: there was no difference, I created my gcp account today, maybe i have to wait

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, the issue was with the urls I returned from uploads
I was returning `https://storage.googleapis.com/${bucket.name}/${blob.name}`
which is old
instead of `https://storage.cloud.google.com/${bucket.name}/${blob.name}`
which is the latest file url

I am to blame here sorry guys

Comment: The endpoint `storage.cloud.google.com` does not support CORS [link](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/using-cors#troubleshooting). The endpoint `storage.googleapis.com` does support CORS. Your comments about old and latest URLs are wrong. Different endpoints have a purpose.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying I was not aware

Comment: Huh... the code shows `// props.url = https://storage.googleapis.com` .. so it seemed like correct one is being tried and still didn't work. Anyways.. good if its resolved.